# Flutter Camera pinch zoom

Tags: flutter, camera, pinchzoom, gesturedetector

I'm trying to create a camera app in Flutter but I keep bumping into zoom issues.
I managed to get the zoom code working via buttons, but when I try to replace those buttons with a GestureDetector, nothing happens.

Below is the camera page. I tried checking if my gestureDetector gets called somewhere by adding a debugLog, but this prints nothing so I think the issue is with calling the detector and not necessarily the code inside the detector

```dart
class CameraPreviewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  CameraPreviewPage({required this.camera});

  @override
  _CameraPreviewPageState createState() => _CameraPreviewPageState();
}

class _CameraPreviewPageState extends State<CameraPreviewPage> {
  late CameraController _cameraController;
  late Future<void> _initializeCameraControllerFuture;
  double zoom = 1.0;
  double _scaleFactor = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _cameraController =
        CameraController(widget.camera, ResolutionPreset.ultraHigh);

    _initializeCameraControllerFuture = _cameraController.initialize();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
       FutureBuilder(
            future: _initializeCameraControllerFuture,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              //The gestureDetector doesn't work
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return
                  GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                    onScaleStart: (details) {
                       zoom = _scaleFactor;
                    },
                    onScaleUpdate: (details) {
                       _scaleFactor = zoom * details.scale;
                       _cameraController.setZoomLevel(_scaleFactor);
                       debugPrint('Gesture updated');
                    },
                    child:CameraPreview(_cameraController));
              } else {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),

        SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          floatingActionButton:
              Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "FABZoomIn",
              child: Icon(
                Icons.zoom_in,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (zoom < 8) {
                  zoom = zoom + 1;
                }
                _cameraController.setZoomLevel(zoom);
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
              heroTag: "FABZoomOut",
              child: Icon(
                Icons.zoom_out,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                if (zoom > 1) {
                  zoom = zoom - 1;
                }
                _cameraController.setZoomLevel(zoom);
              },
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "FABCamera",
                child: Icon(Icons.camera, color: Colors.white),
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  _takePicture(context);
                })
          ]),
        ))
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cameraController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

EDIT: I've also tried using onTap to see if this gives me any more insights in what could be going wrong, but onTap also doesn't get registered.

Comment: Are you saying the hit test is not being detected ? Did you try putting a simple `onTap` on the GestureDetector and see if it is getting called ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I tried using onTap with debugPrint('Tapped') and this also doesn't work.

Comment: Use the simple `print` instead of `debugPrint` once.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Still the same result

Comment: @NisanthReddy I moved the GestureDetector so that it's the top level widget (containing the stack) and this solved is. However this might cause issues if the camera hasn't been loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, you shouldn't have to do that. I have added an answer. Check out if that helps.

Comment: Did you try InteractiveViewer widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the first `child` inside the `children` of a `Stack` is rendered first and all the other `children` are rendered on top of the first `child`.

So, your `GestureDetector` will never trigger since the other children are handling the tap and obstructing the `GestureDetector` from receiving any hits.

Just move your `GestureDetector` to the end of the `children` list.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    SafeArea(
      ....
    ), 
    GestureDetector(
      ....
    ),
  ],
)
```

If your definitely need the `CameraPreview` at the bottom and the `SafeArea` to be rendered on top it, then separate your `CameraPreview` into another `Container` and have your `GestureDetector` as a separate widget at the end of the `children` list.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      child: CameraPreview(),
    ),
    SafeArea(
      ....
    ), 
    GestureDetector(
      ....
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: This is not working for me using Camera^0.7.0. After using the GestureDetector to change the scale, my code prints at .takePicture: 
`await _initializeControllerFuture;
print('here2');
final image = await controller!.takePicture();
print('here3');
`
"here3" does not print and no picture is taken.  This code works fine when I do not use touch the screen and take a photo

Comment: follow up to this.  using a slider to zoom only works on the outward facing camera, if I switch to the selfie view, the slider zoom breaks the button that captures the pictures.  Flutter can be so indiosyncratic